# why does ruby need so many different types of closure?

Tags: ruby

As far as I can tell, there are essentially three different kinds of closure in Ruby; methods, procs and lambdas. I know that there are differences between them, but could we not just get away having one type that accommodates all possible use-cases?

Methods can already be passed around like procs and lambdas by calling `self.method(method_name)`, and the only significant differences that I'm aware of between procs and lambdas is that lambdas check arity and procs do crazy things when you try to use `return`. So couldn't we just merge them all into one and be done with it?

Comment: Could you not apply this same question to why 'x' programming language have so many kinds of numbers, because each kind of number is used in different ways, or why there are so many different kinds of quotes, as they usually all act a little differently?  Can't we have one quoting and one kind of number to rule them all?

Comment: @vgoff There is no point in assimilating all those questions. They all have different reason.

Comment: That is my thought too, lambda's have their purpose as specialized Procs just like Integers have their purpose as specialized numbers.  I don't really want someone deciding that I can't have a Proc or lambda.  I want both. :)

Comment: @vgoff What's to stop someone from wanting both Procs and Lambdas and then a third option? And then someone else not wanting someone deciding they should be limited to only three. Add a fourth and then a fifth and sixth. Limitations can be a good thing. It's why it's called Ruby "Core". I'm not saying your conclusion isn't correct. I'm saying your reason might be a bit dangerous. It could quickly lead to [The Homer Car](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Homer) =)

Comment: I've always thought methods are not closures, the only context they have is their object context. Difference between `lambda` and blocks is not that big, just a convenience.

Comment: @vgoff I'm fine with having different kinds of objects for different tasks, I just feel like the functionality of lambdas and procs (and maybe even methods) could be merged quite easily without causing any significant problems.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell That is a lot of what my thoughts are too.  The core-team decides what is available, and there must be some reason that there are the four kinds of blocks that we use, the distinction between lambda and Proc.  That is not a limitation, we are free to create things that may be closely related to Proc, it is just a class, after all.  It is up to Matz or the other relevant teams to accept or deny them in core. It is an open language, there is *nothing* stopping them from doing so. Not a bad thing. Power and responsibility, being what it is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, there are essentially three different kinds of closure in Ruby; methods, procs and lambdas.

No, there are two: methods aren't closures, only procs and lambdas are. (Or at least *can* be, most of them aren't.)

There are two ways of packaging up a piece of executable code for reuse in Ruby: methods and blocks. Strictly speaking, blocks aren't necessary, you can get by with just methods. But blocks are meant to be extremely light-weight, conceptually, semantically and syntactically. That's not true for methods.

Because they are meant to be light-weight and easy to use, blocks behave different from methods in some respects, e.g. how arguments are bound to parameters. Block parameters are bound more like the left-hand side of an assignment than like method parameters.

Examples:

Passing a single array to multiple parameters:

```
def foo(a, b) end
foo([1, 2, 3]) # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

a, b = [1, 2, 3]
# a == 1; b == 2

[[1, 2, 3]].each {|a, b| puts "a == #{a}; b == #{b}" }
# a == 1; b ==2
```

Passing less arguments than parameters:

```
def foo(a, b, c) end
foo(1, 2) # ArgumentError

a, b, c = 1, 2
# a == 1; b == 2; c == nil

[[1, 2]].each {|a, b, c| puts "a == #{a}; b == #{b}; c == #{c}" }
# a == 1; b == 2; c ==
```

Passing more arguments than parameters:

```
def foo(a, b) end
foo(1, 2, 3) # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

a, b = 1, 2, 3
# a == 1; b == 2

[[1, 2, 3]].each {|a, b| puts "a == #{a}; b == #{b}" }
# a == 1; b == 2
```

[By the way: none of the blocks above are closures.]

This allows, for example, the `Enumerable` protocol which always yields a *single* element to the block to work with `Hash`es: you just make the *single* element an `Array` of `[key, value]` and rely on the implicit array destructuring of the block:

```
{one: 1, two: 2}.each {|k, v| puts "#{key} is assigned to #{value}" }
```

is much easier to understand than what you would have to otherwise write:

```
{one: 1, two: 2}.each {|el| puts "#{el.first} is assigned to #{el.last}" }
```

Another difference between blocks and methods is that methods use the `return` keyword to return a value whereas blocks use the `next` keyword.

If you agree that it makes sense to have both methods and blocks in the language, then it is just a small step to also accept the existence of both procs and lambdas, because they behave like blocks and methods, respectively:

- procs `return` from the enclosing method (just like blocks) and they bind arguments exactly like blocks do
- lambdas `return` from themselves (just like methods) and they bind arguments exactly like methods do.

IOW: the proc/lambda dichotomy just mirrors the block/method dichotomy.

Note that there are actually quite a lot more cases to consider. For example, what does `self` mean? Does it mean

- whatever `self` was at the point the block was written
- whatever `self` is at the point the block is run
- the block itself

And what about `return`? Does it mean

- return from the method the block is written in
- return from the method the block is run in
- return from the block itself?

This *already* gives you *nine* possibilities, even *without* taking into account the Ruby-specific peculiarities of parameter binding.

Now, for reasons of encapsulation, #2 above are really bad ideas, so that reduces our choices somewhat.

As always, it's a matter of taste of the language designer. There are other such redundancies in Ruby as well: why do you need both instance variables and local variables? If lexical scopes were objects, then local variables would just be instance variables of the lexical scope and you wouldn't need local variables. And why do you need both instance variables and methods? One of them is enough: a getter/setter pair of methods can replace an instance variable (see Newspeak for an example of such a language) and first-class procedures assigned to instance variables can replace methods (see Self, Python, JavaScript). Why do you need both classes and modules? If you allow classes to be mixed-in, then you can get rid of modules and use classes both as classes and mixins. And why do you need mixins at all? If everything is a method call, classes automatically become mixins anyway (again, see Newspeak for an example). And of course, if you allow inheritance directly between objects you don't need classes at all (see Self, Io, Ioke, Seph, JavaScript)

Comment: My bad, I thought closure and 'packaging up a piece of executable code for reuse' were synonymous.

Answer (score 3):

Some pretty good explanation http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/ but i am guessing you want a bit more deeply philosophical explanation...

I believe the answer to "but could we not just get away having one type that accommodates all possible use-cases?", is that you can get away using just one.

The reason they exist is that ruby is trying to make the developer as productive as possible using expressions from both functional and object oriented paradigms, which makes the different types of closure "syntactic sugar".

Comment: Funnily enough, reading that exact article is what motivated me to ask the question. It made everything seem so overly complicated, and I couldn't help but think that things would be a lot easier if there was just one type of closure (as in Smalltalk, which Ruby has many similarities with).